# How to set dynamic value to button from array in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular7

I am new to angular and i want to show dynamic data with edit and delete button i have done so many thing right now data are display properly with header and etc but now i want to give edit button.

So i am passing each records of id to view and when i loop through to edit button it will display number of button rather than one button.

Here i am providing component.html code

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%" border="1">
    <thead class="thead" style="background-color:#3f51b5; color:white;">
      <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let label of model.label">
          {{label}}
        </th>

        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let key of model.TemplateJson">
        <td scope="row" *ngFor="let k of key">{{k.value}}</td>
        <th *ngFor="let btn of model.Id">
            <button mat-raised-button   style="width:100%; background-color:#3f51b5; color:white;" [routerLink]="['/formBuilder', {edit: btn}]">Edit</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

In model.Id getting list of id that why i am getting so many button.

Here i am including image of output for clear idea.
[image]

Edit

Json object

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"number",
      "label":"GR No",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"number-1557737728450",
      "value":"1234"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701360234",
      "value":"Jerry",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701374890",
      "value":"Foster",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Class",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557737708598",
      "value":"X",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1554701421490",
      "value":"2019-04-30"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Comment",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557396998516",
      "value":"New Admission",
      "subtype":"text"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"number",
      "label":"GR No",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"number-1557737728450",
      "value":"2345"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701360234",
      "value":"Jeffrey",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701374890",
      "value":"Tucker",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Class",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557737708598",
      "value":"X",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1554701421490",
      "value":"2019-05-01"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Comment",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557396998516",
      "value":"New Admission",
      "subtype":"text"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"number",
      "label":"GR No",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"number-1557737728450",
      "value":"3456"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701360234",
      "value":"Anne",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701374890",
      "value":"Cloyd",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Class",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557737708598",
      "value":"XI",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1554701421490",
      "value":"2019-05-03"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Comment",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557396998516",
      "value":"New Admission",
      "subtype":"text"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"number",
      "label":"GR No",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"number-1557737728450",
      "value":"4567"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701360234",
      "value":"Kristina",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701374890",
      "value":"Baker",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Class",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557737708598",
      "value":"XI",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1554701421490",
      "value":"2019-05-05"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Comment",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557396998516",
      "value":"New Admission",
      "subtype":"text"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"number",
      "label":"GR No",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"number-1557737728450",
      "value":"56789"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701360234",
      "value":"Christopher",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1554701374890",
      "value":"Smith",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Class",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557737708598",
      "value":"XII",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1554701421490",
      "value":"2019-04-29"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Comment",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557396998516",
      "value":"New Admission",
      "subtype":"text"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Name",
      "name":"text - 1554220470561",
      "value":"Marilyn",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557726629007",
      "value":"marilyn@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"PhoneNumber",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557738193617",
      "value":"9898989898",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"textarea",
      "label":"Message",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"textarea-1557738218005",
      "value":"We had issue regarding our existing website. Please help us.",
      "subtype":"textarea"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Name",
      "name":"text - 1554220470561",
      "value":"Elizabeth",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557726629007",
      "value":"elizabeth@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"PhoneNumber",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557738193617",
      "value":"9898989898",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"textarea",
      "label":"Message",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"textarea-1557738218005",
      "value":"I have placed wrong order and i want to cancel this my order. ",
      "subtype":"textarea"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Name",
      "name":"text - 1554220470561",
      "value":"Carmelita",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557726629007",
      "value":"carmelita@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"PhoneNumber",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557738193617",
      "value":"9898989898",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"textarea",
      "label":"Message",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"textarea-1557738218005",
      "value":"My website crash when place order",
      "subtype":"textarea"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049946945",
      "value":"Richard",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049947305",
      "value":"Brown",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557740025898",
      "value":"richard@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Blood Group",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049953585",
      "value":"B+",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date Of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1555049951249",
      "value":"2019-02-06"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049946945",
      "value":"Paul",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049947305",
      "value":"Stein",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557740025898",
      "value":"paul@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Blood Group",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049953585",
      "value":"O+",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date Of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1555049951249",
      "value":"2019-02-20"
   }
][  
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient FirstName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049946945",
      "value":"Levi",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Patient LastName",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049947305",
      "value":"Stjohn",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Email",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1557740025898",
      "value":"levi@gmail.com",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"text",
      "label":"Blood Group",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"text-1555049953585",
      "value":"AB+",
      "subtype":"text"
   },
   {  
      "type":"date",
      "label":"Date Of Birth",
      "className":"form-control",
      "name":"date-1555049951249",
      "value":"2019-03-08"
   }
]
```

Edit:2

```
 this.model = new FormRecords();
    this.model.Id = this.formId;
    this.model.label = this.label;
    this.model.TemplateJson = this.keys;
```

Comment: can you please share your `model.TemplateJson` Array

Comment: @bhagwattupe i am not getting id on that model.TemplateJson

Comment: You seem to be creating a new edit button on each row for each id. You might want to remove the ngFor, with the edit buttons? At least if I understand you correctly

Comment: @VitoInfinito Yes but if i remove ngFor and use model.Id then my url look like http://localhost:4200/formBuilder;0=9;1=10;2=11;3=12;4=13 beacuse it return list of id

Comment: You want to get your current edited id on click button. please send your `modal` object json

Comment: @bhagwattupe i have added json object

Comment: In your object dont have `model.TemplateJson` array

Comment: @bhagwattupe list of object return on model.TemplateJson and i must clear to you in this model.TemplateJson we don't have id

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this loop `*ngFor="let btn of model.Id"`, remove the loop, and use your record id (I guess it would be on key.Id or something) in your routerLink params

```
<th>
   <button mat-raised-button [routerLink]="['/formBuilder',yourRowId, {edit: btn}]">Edit</button>
</th>
```

Comment: but model.id give me list of id so can i identify for each of records

Comment: after your solution my url look like http://localhost:4200/formBuilder;0=9;1=10;2=11;3=12;4=13

Comment: so first of all if model.id contains list of ids , call it model.ids (your code can be self documented)
What you need is the id of the current row,

Comment: See my updated answer, btw you localhost url is not accessible on the internet

Comment: Yes i want current row id

Comment: problem is i am not getting my id from the key

Comment: We are not foreteller, Without providing more information about your objects and `model.TemplatreJson` we can't tell you where is your row id

Comment: add `{{key | json}}` in your row, then you will see your structure of data

Comment: I have added json in my question please can check it

Comment: Id is not within the json object

Comment: So ask the dev providing data to include `id`

Comment: can you help me like how to include list of id in model.TemplateJson i have added code in EDIT:2